# R - como amostrar pares a partir de um vetor sem repetir valores?

Tags: array, r

Eu estou tentando criar 100 pares a partir de um vetor com 200 valores. Eu construi um vetor seguindo uma distribuição normal da seguinte forma:

```
vetor=rnorm(200,mean=30,sd=6)
```

E agora eu quero extrair 100 pares desses valores, mas sem repetir nenhum deles.
Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
pares=replicate(100,sample(vetor,2,replace=FALSE))
```

Nesse caso, `replace=FALSE` evitou que fossem amostrados pares iguais, mas alguns valores do vetor entraram em mais de um par, e outros valores não entraram em par nenhum.

O que eu quero é que todos os valores façam parte de algum par e que todos os pares sejam diferentes.

Algúem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É mais fácil fazer isso do que pensa. Mais exatamente, não é preciso usar o `replicate`. Basta ver que `sample(vetor)` produz uma permutação do seu argumento. (Sem repetições.)

```
set.seed(3604)    # para que os resultados sejam reprodutíveis 
vetor <- rnorm(200, mean = 30, sd = 6)

pares <- matrix(sample(vetor), nrow = 2)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou direitinho!